# PC Windows8 kaspersky installation

Tags: kaspersky

I am trying to install a Kaspersky update on my computer but it keeps coming up with An error occured and you must close iphlpsvc.dll to continue.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Open the task manager. Click the services tab then find the IP HELPER or iphlpsvc. Right click on it and stop the service.